# How to reproduce this p value result from Prism manually in Excel?

Tags: statistical-significance, excel

Can I get some help with reproducing this p value in Excel?
The Ho is theta(CAU) = theta(AA), the Ha is theta(CAU) =(not equal) theta(AA).

I tried in Excel by finding the z- score first, then 2*(1- norm.s.dist(z-score,1). I got 0.88 though.

Here are the stats and particularly P-value of 0.99 obtained from Prism
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is from the procedure `prop.test` in R:

```
prop.test(c(66,55),c(95,78), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions
            without continuity correction

data:  c(66, 55) out of c(95, 78)
X-squared = 0.022, df = 1, p-value = 0.8821
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.1475618  0.1267791
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6947368 0.7051282
```

Notice that the two estimates for the probability of being over 50 are $\hat\theta_{CAU} = 0.695$
and $\hat\theta_{AA} = 0.705.$ For sample sizes below
100 these estimates can be viewed as essentially
identical. So it is no surprise that $H_0: \theta_{CAU}=\theta_{AA}$ cannot be rejected.
In R, the P-value of the test is 0.88 >> 0.05.

While R is meticulous to give exact P-values even
when they are nowhere near 0.05, many software
programs are not. If the P-value exceeds 0.2, some
programs will just print `P-val > 0.2` and not
bother with the exact value. (After all, nobody is going to 'reject at the 25% level'.)

I guess my answer to your question is that you may
not be able to reproduce the P-value 0.99 in any other
statistical software program.

There are several ways to do this test comparing
two binomial proportions. Most of them involve using
a normal or chi-squared approximation. Some use
'continuity corrections' and some do not. Some
use a 'pooled estimate' of the standard error of the
difference (denominator of z) and some do not.
Fortunately, for P-values around 0.01 or 0.05 most
of these methods give nearly equal results.

---

*Addendum:* A different approach to analyzing
these data would be to look at a $2\times 2$ table of counts, to see if proportions over and
under 50 are 'homogenous' in the two groups.
In turn, the table can be analyzed using a chi-squared test or using Fisher's Exact test.
Here are the results with yet two more P-values
considerably above 5%.

```
TBL = rbind(c(29,23),c(66,65))
TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   29   23
[2,]   66   65

chisq.test(TBL)

         Pearson's Chi-squared test 
      with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.2439, df = 1, 
  p-value = 0.6214

fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.6229
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6201997 2.5006117
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.240293
```